# Wait while Promise answer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Before read: Sorry for my english level.

```
var match = matchPromise != undefined ? matchPromise.then(ret_val =>
    {
        return ret_val;
    })
    : false;

    if (match) {
        //continue here after Promise response
    }
```

My question is, how to wait before enter in the `if` ? because everytimes `match == false`, but `match` can be `true` if hes answered by the promise.

I hope you understand my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you need is `Promise.all([...promises])`. If you call `Promise.all([match]).then((val) => ...)` then place your if inside the then callback, it will resolve match in every case (if promise, it waits for promise and resolves, if value, it resolves immediately)

Comment: @Quentin I don't think it's a duplicate of THAT specific question... Poorly asked, but I think his problem was "How do I handle a value that could be a promise or a value?"

Comment: `(matchPromise || Promise.reject("not defined")).then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: @quentin i agree to fabio. This isnt really an exact dupe ...

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more explanation. Quentin must have duped it because your code tries to get the resolve value of a promise in a synchronous way, this is not possible. You can however turn your possibly non promise value into a promise with `Promise.all` and `Promise.reject` as suggested in comments or `Promise.resolve` as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
(matchPromise != null
  ? matchPromise
  : Promise.resolve(false)
).then(match => {
    // continue here after Promise response
});
```

Notice that you cannot wait for anything without making your code asychronous.

Answer (score -2):

You can wrap a possible promise in `Promise.resolve` and use `.then` on it

```
Promise.resolve(matchPromise).then(
  match=>{
    if(match){...
  }
)
```

To clarify: you cannot read a promise in a synchronous way, your only options for a promise is to use `.then` or `async/await`. There is a way to turn a synchronous value (in your case `undefined`) to a promise with `Promise.resolve` (in your case a promise of undefined).

So now it doesn't matter anymore if `matchPromise` is a promise or not because you make sure it is and then process it in `.then` that will either give you the resolved value or the `undefined` value, either way; the result of the if statement is the same.

Comment: @Quentin I thought `matchPromise` was either undefined or a promise so you can't do `.then` on undefined but can't assume the resolve of `matchPromise` is undefined/falsy when it is a promise. Therefor wrap it in `Promise.resolve(undefined or something resolving to possibly false).then(result=>didn't matter if it was undefined result would just be undefined)`